# Fast templating for Moq?

Tags: resharper, moq, template-engine

it is very routine to make by hand many Moq's Setup() calls in order to make a mock of an entire set of interface methods. I would like to find a way to pre-fill mocking expressions, with dummy responses.

Is there a way to do so? I use ReSharper if it is relevant.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Visual Studio, you can create a code snippet, for example something like:

moqq

Then when you use your **moqq + TAB + TAB**, it will appear something like:

```
Mock<Interface> mock = new Mock<Interface>();
mock.Setup(x => x.MyMethod(params)).Return(return);
```

And you can do all of this only writting moqq.

Even you can put some "points" in your code snippets, then when you hit TAB again you will pass for example from Interface to MyMethod. This way you don´t need even to touch your mouse to change all the variable names ;)

Follow this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165393(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Using a Resharper "Live Template" based on [Oscar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22184903/389424):

```
Mock<$interfaceToMock$> mock$interfaceToMock$ = new Mock<$interfaceToMock$>();
mock$interfaceToMock$.Setup(x => x.$expectedMethod$).Returns($returnValue$);
```

Entire Resharper DotSettings content containing macro's etc (based on R# 2020.3):

```
<wpf:ResourceDictionary xml:space="preserve"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                        xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                        xmlns:ss="urn:shemas-jetbrains-com:settings-storage-xaml"
                        xmlns:wpf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=E53EF07BEAF6964C83AD78E1B75E3837/@KeyIndexDefined">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=E53EF07BEAF6964C83AD78E1B75E3837/Shortcut/@EntryValue">moqq</s:String>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=E53EF07BEAF6964C83AD78E1B75E3837/Description/@EntryValue">Moq mock</s:String>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=E53EF07BEAF6964C83AD78E1B75E3837/Text/@EntryValue">Mock&lt;$interfaceToMock$&gt; mock$interfaceToMock$ = new Mock&lt;$interfaceToMock$&gt;();&#xD; mock$interfaceToMock$.Setup(x =&gt; x.$expectedMethod$).Returns($returnValue$);</s:String>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=E53EF07BEAF6964C83AD78E1B75E3837/Reformat/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=E53EF07BEAF6964C83AD78E1B75E3837/ShortenQualifiedReferences/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=E53EF07BEAF6964C83AD78E1B75E3837/Categories/=Tests/@EntryIndexedValue">Tests</s:String>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=E53EF07BEAF6964C83AD78E1B75E3837/Applicability/=Live/@EntryIndexedValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=E53EF07BEAF6964C83AD78E1B75E3837/Scope/=C3001E7C0DA78E4487072B7E050D86C5/@KeyIndexDefined">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=E53EF07BEAF6964C83AD78E1B75E3837/Scope/=C3001E7C0DA78E4487072B7E050D86C5/Type/@EntryValue">InCSharpFile</s:String>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=E53EF07BEAF6964C83AD78E1B75E3837/Scope/=C3001E7C0DA78E4487072B7E050D86C5/CustomProperties/=minimumLanguageVersion/@EntryIndexedValue">2.0</s:String>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=E53EF07BEAF6964C83AD78E1B75E3837/Field/=interfaceToMock/@KeyIndexDefined">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=E53EF07BEAF6964C83AD78E1B75E3837/Field/=interfaceToMock/Expression/@EntryValue">guessExpectedType("")</s:String>
    <s:Int64 x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=E53EF07BEAF6964C83AD78E1B75E3837/Field/=interfaceToMock/InitialRange/@EntryValue">2</s:Int64>
    <s:Int64 x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=E53EF07BEAF6964C83AD78E1B75E3837/Field/=interfaceToMock/Order/@EntryValue">0</s:Int64>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=E53EF07BEAF6964C83AD78E1B75E3837/Field/=expectedMethod/@KeyIndexDefined">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Int64 x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=E53EF07BEAF6964C83AD78E1B75E3837/Field/=expectedMethod/Order/@EntryValue">1</s:Int64>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=E53EF07BEAF6964C83AD78E1B75E3837/Field/=returnValue/@KeyIndexDefined">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Int64 x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/LiveTemplates/Template/=E53EF07BEAF6964C83AD78E1B75E3837/Field/=returnValue/Order/@EntryValue">2</s:Int64>
</wpf:ResourceDictionary>
```

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/janv8000/7e4c97d1e76769b09f417ae00e002147)